# Chrome extension Rich Notifications not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, rich-notifications

I am building a chrome extension and I am currently in the process of trying to add Rich Notifications. I have currently included the "notifications" permission in my manifest.json file and I have added this to my background.js:

```js
var options = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "Congratulations!",
  message: "You have successfully created a notification!",
  iconUrl: "greenTick.png",
  progress: 100
};

chrome.notifications.create("", options, callback);
```

The code currently reaches the callback function and I display an alert through it just to make sure it does, but the actual notification does not appear on the screen. Can anyone please provide any input on why that might be happening and on what I can do to fix it please? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `"basic"` type notifications don't allow progress indicator. Delete `progress` from `options`

Comment: Great, thanks, that worked! :)

Comment: "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running notifications.create: The progress value should not be specified for non-progress notification"
Learn how to use Devtools. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools